# How to ping from a router

Tags: lan, ping, internet-speed

I am trying to determine current download speed using ping.
I want to calculate download speed for the router and not for any connection or device.

#### How can I ping 8.8.8.8/google.com from a router ?

I have Linux and MacOS computers in the network.

Comment: I just noticed this. You want to determine the **download speed** using the **ping** ? That's... not how it works. The two are *related*, but not that much. A good ping indicates a responsive connection, but you can have a good ping with a not-that-fast connection. You can have 50ms of ping and 500Mbps down with optic fiber. On my VDSL connection I'm getting 10ms and 30Mbps down. If you want a download speed, use a speed test service.

Comment: Also, the term "current download speed" is ambiguous. Do you mean the speed at which downloads are actually occurring? Or do you mean the maximum speed at which downloads could occur whether or not anything's being downloaded?

Comment: By current speed I mean the speed at which downloads are occuring, so when nothing is being downloaded current speed would be 0 Mb/s

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ping **from** the router, or basically to do anything **from** the router, you need to have access to some sort of command interface, be it a web page (192.168.1.1, things like that) or a command line (if you router runs OpenWRT, DDWRT or anything that runs Linux, you should be able to telnet or ssh into it and issue a ping command).

What is the model of the router, and what firmware does it run?

Comment: dlink 2750U and it runs the default firmware

Comment: Try to telnet into the router. If it asks for an username, try admin, and for the password, try the password set for the web interface.

Comment: @danielturner - If you are using the default firmware, then it does not,have the ability to ping websites.  Which means unless you use OpenWRT/DD-WRT on the device you will be unable to accomplish what you want.  As pointed out your ping (latency) to a website has very little effect, on the how amount of bandwidth you will use while connected to an ip address.